# SYS_TICK handler function is not getting called after enabling flags in SysTick Control and Status Register

Tags: stm32, system, cortex-m, stm32f4discovery

I'm using STM32F407G-DISC1 board, SYS_TICK handler is not getting called after enabling flags in SysTick Control and Status Register which is at 0xE000E010 memory mapped location.  SysTick Reload Value Register value is set to 15999.

```
void init_systick_timer(uint32_t tick_hz)
{
    uint32_t *pSRVR = (uint32_t*)0xE000E014;
    uint32_t *pSCSR = (uint32_t*)0xE000E010;

    /* calculation of reload value */
    uint32_t count_value = (SYSTICK_TIM_CLK/tick_hz)-1;

    //Clear the value of SVR
    *pSRVR &= ~(0x00FFFFFFFF);

    //load the value in to SVR
    *pSRVR |= count_value;

    //do some settings
    *pSCSR |= ( 1 << 1); //Enables SysTick exception request:
    *pSCSR |= ( 1 << 2);  //Indicates the clock source, processor clock source

    //enable the systick
    *pSCSR |= ( 1 << 0); //enables the counter

}
void  SysTick_Handler(void)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather recomment to **do not** reinvent the wheel and use standard STM provided CMSIS headers.

Your way of defining the registers is incorrect. It will not work correctly if decide to read theis values back. Compiler will simple optimize the reads from the memory out. They have to be `volatile`.

But abstracting from that you need to enable the interrupt in the NVIC controller. Without that the systick timer will only set the pending flag without invoking the handler.